# Cognos Configuration

Tags: dispatcher, cognos

I am trying integrate cognos dispatcher url into my applicaiton, getting below error while accessing the dispatcher url,

Caused by: com.cognos.org.apache.axis.AxisFault: CM-REQ-4342 An error occurred with the client.
at

com.cognos.org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:223)
at Please let me know for any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly integrate an external application with Cognos. You supposed use Cognos Mashup Service. You can find some samples installation_location/webcontent/samples/sdk/cms (Note: path may change depending on the version of Cognos you are using)